# ruby method - how to reduce the number of params in a method?

Tags: ruby, optimization, parameters

I know that fewer params is better and more than 2 (or 3 or 4, depending on the literature) is a code smell.

If I have code with params, such as the following:

```
class DoubleSeries
  def self.generate_sequences(seq1_start, seq2_start, seq1_step, seq2_step, iterations)
    seq1,seq2=seq1_start,seq2_start
    result=[]
    (1..iterations).each do
      result << seq1 << seq2
      seq1+=seq1_step
      seq2+=seq2_step
    end
    result
  end
end
```

how can I reduce the number of parameters from 5 when they all serve a function?

Comment: I would argue that since all parameters are required, you could just take a hash and go from there. But I'll wait to see if someone has a more elegant solution.

Comment: Parameter object is the canonical response. Personally I find the original parameter order wrong, and once it's right, their tight coupling becomes crystal clear. I'd probably also use "times".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose if you wanna go all out strict with the [Sandi Metz rules](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/50655960596/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers) then the OOP way is the way to go.

```
class Sequence
  attr_reader :start, :step

  initialize(start, step)
    @start = start
    @step = step
  end
end

sequence_1 = Sequence.new(seq1_start, seq1_step)
sequence_2 = Sequence.new(seq2_start, seq2_step)

class DoubleSeries
  def self.generate_sequences(sequence_1, sequence_2, iterations)
    item_1, item_2 = sequence_1.start, sequence_2.start
    result=[]
    iterations.times do
      result << item_1 << item_2
      item_1 += sequence_1.step
      item_2 += sequence_2.step
    end
    result
  end
end
```

[My code (michael):

[image]

Comment: Nice of you to post the editor screenshots! It's looking good. :thumbsup:

Comment: Sure, always looking for questions and answers that show others the gritty detailed when they are stuck.

Comment: @ArupRakshit That's actually Michael's edit, but I believe it's vim running under Ubuntu.

Comment: Perhaps `sudo apt-get install vim`?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Edited to use `#times` instead of `#each`.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot do without a parameter, then that parameter must stay.  Just because methods with small signatures are preferred, that does not mean that long method signatures are bad when each argument is necessary.

However, if you really want to cheat and shorten the signature, you could try:

```
class DoubleSeries
  def self.generate_sequences(array_args)
    seq1_start, seq2_start, seq1_step, seq2_step, iterations = *array_args
    seq1,seq2=seq1_start,seq2_start
    result=[]
    (1..iterations).each do
      result << seq1 << seq2
      seq1+=seq1_step
      seq2+=seq2_step
    end
    result
  end
end
```

However, I would argue that what I wrote is less clear than what you originally wrote (because the arguments are much more ambiguous).  I just gave a code example to show you that you could only have a single argument, but that it may not be the best approach.

Another way to do what you want would be to change how you generate sequences.  E.g

```
class DoubleSeries
  def self.generate_sequence(seq1_start, seq1_step, iterations)
    seq1=seq1_start
    result=[]
    (1..iterations).each do
      result << seq1
      seq1+=seq1_step
    end
    result
  end        
end

x = DoubleSeries.generate_sequence(1,5,5)
y = DoubleSeries.generate_sequence(4,6,5)
x.zip(y).flatten
```

Or, using Ruby 2.0 and [Lazy Enumerators](http://patshaughnessy.net/2013/4/3/ruby-2-0-works-hard-so-you-can-be-lazy):

```
range = 1..Integer::INFINITY
seq_1 = range.lazy.collect{|n| (n-start_1 % seq_1_step) == 0}.first(iterations)
seq_2 = range.lazy.collect{|n| (n-start_2 % seq_2_step) == 0}.first(iterations)
seq_1.zip(seq_2).flatten
```

Comment: Davidann, you posted my thoughts exactly. Variable number of arguments isn't the clearest solution though. I'd agree. +1